# Comparing a Moment object to a Date object - how does it work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

I ran into the following code (nodejs v10.15):

```
...
return l.createdAt < pdate;
```

where `l.createdAt` is an instance of `Date` and `pdate` is a Moment object.

I would expect something like:

```
pdate.isAfter(l.createdAt)
```

or

```
moment(l.createdAt).isBefore(pdate)
```

but the weird thing is: I checked a few examples and it looks like this comparison works just fine, even though two different types of objects are compared!

And my question is: how does `l.createdAt < pdate` work?

Is JS "smart" enough and it knows it should coerce the right side into a Date object?

A screenshot from my IDE:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pdate.isAfter(l.createdAt)` work not because JS is smart enough but because the moment lib handle that case.

What you said first works because the moment object is cast to primitive number representing timestamp (in ms) (cf. [MDM doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive))

```js
console.log(moment('2019-12-12') < new Date())// true
console.log(moment('2021-12-12') < new Date())// false

console.log(new Date() < moment('2019-12-12'))// false
console.log(new Date() < moment('2021-12-12'))// true

console.log(+moment('2019-12-12'))// 1576105200000
console.log(+new Date())// 1595454345427
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

and look at this also

```js
const object1 = {
  foo:'bar',
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    if (hint === 'number') {
      return 42;
    }
    return null;
  }
};
console.log(object1 < 23);// false
console.log(object1 < 55);// true
console.log(+object1);// 42
```

Comment: please read the question carefully... I know that `pdate.isAfter(l.createdAt)` works and why, that was not what I asked about

Comment: what cast are you talking about?

Comment: yeah because of the cast, it works in browser or node. (look at my response with the symbol.toPrimitive). when you call object with operator `+` or `<`, it cast your object to primitive.

Comment: What is being cast and into which primitive type? _That's_ exactly what I'm trying to figure out!

Comment: moment object and date object are cast to primitive number representing timestamp (in ms), you have the info in comments in my example.

Comment: This makes sense! Can you please add this information ("cast to primitive number representing timestamp (in ms)") to the answer and provide references/links to that document this behavior?